# Export sqlite db in phonegap app

Tags: sqlite, cordova

We have an app using cordova (phonegap) and his own sqlite DB (I mean we didn't install an external sqlite).

We need to backup the DB into the SD memory but we have problems to export the sqlite file from phonegap to SD.

May anybody help us?

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific in your questions. What have you tried?

Comment: I am also looking for the same. Did you find solution?

Answer (score 2):

A couple years late, I know, but this is working for me on Cordova 5.4.1 and running on Android (I think iOS uses cordova.file.application too, but I have not tested yet):

```
this.getdbfilename = function () {
    return "dbfile.db";
};

this.getdbdirectory = function() {
    return cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + "databases/";
};


// copy DB file out to non-private app directory.
this.copyDBFileOut = function (outfilename) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.getdbdirectory() + this.getdbfilename(), function (fileEntry) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL((cordova.file.externalDataDirectory || cordova.file.documentsDirectory), function(dirEntry) {
            fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry, outfilename, function() { console.log("copyDBFileOut() succeeded");}, this.errorHandler);
        });
      });
  };
```

Comment: Sir we can copy db file to sdcard or we may store it to server, if we loss our phone then user will ask restore db file from other device, then we to restore it into the same file right.. But i am trying this couple of days not getting any working solution.. can u please check it out this? Pls help me if you know

Answer (score 1):

This sounds good with Cordova 3.5 and org.apache.cordova.file 1.2.1

Some variations needed for differents path.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("file:///data/data/my-app-name/databases/name-of.db", function(fs) {
                var parent = "file://mnt/external_sd/";
                var newName = "mybackup.db";
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(parent, function(directoryEntry) {
                    fs.copyTo(directoryEntry, newName, function() {
                        alert("Backup ok");
                    }, failFiles);
                });
            }, failFiles);

function failFiles(error) {        
  if (error.code == FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR) alert("Message : NOT_FOUND_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.SECURITY_ERR) alert("Message : SECURITY_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.ABORT_ERR) alert("Message : ABORT_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.NOT_READABLE_ERR) alert("Message : NOT_READABLE_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.ENCODING_ERR) alert("Message : ENCODING_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR) alert("Message : NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR) alert("Message : INVALID_STATE_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.SYNTAX_ERR) alert("Message : SYNTAX_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR) alert("Message :  INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) alert("Message : QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.PATH_EXISTS_ERR) alert("Message : PATH_EXISTS_ERR" )  
}
```

Comment: Sir we can copy db file to sdcard or we may store it to server, if we loss our phone then user will ask restore db file from other device, then we to restore it into the same file right.. But i am trying this couple of days not getting any working solution.. can u please check it out this

Answer (score 0):

Many time ago...but i think this was the solution:

```
function failFiles(error) {        
  if (error.code == FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR) alert("Message : NOT_FOUND_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.SECURITY_ERR) alert("Message : SECURITY_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.ABORT_ERR) alert("Message : ABORT_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.NOT_READABLE_ERR) alert("Message : NOT_READABLE_ERR" )
  else if (error.code ==   FileError.ENCODING_ERR) alert("Message : ENCODING_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR) alert("Message : NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR) alert("Message : INVALID_STATE_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.SYNTAX_ERR) alert("Message : SYNTAX_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR) alert("Message :  INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) alert("Message : QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR" )
  else if (error.code == FileError.PATH_EXISTS_ERR) alert("Message : PATH_EXISTS_ERR" )  
}  

function successDump() {    
}  

//Export DB. Get the file        file:///data/data/yourproject/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db  
//and save in the SD with the name yourproject.db
function copyBdtoSD() {    
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, successDump, failFiles);            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///data/data/yourproject/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db", copyFileToSd, failFiles);
}


function copyFileToSd(entry) {    
    var parent = "file:///mnt/sdcard",
        parentName = parent.substring(parent.lastIndexOf('/')+1),        
        parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry(parentName, parent);       
    var newName = "yourproject.db";

   // copy the file
   entry.copyTo(parentEntry, newName, successExport, failFiles);    
}
```

Comment: Sir we can copy db file to sdcard or we may store it to server, if we loss our phone then user will ask restore db file from other device, then we to restore it into the same file right.. But i am trying this couple of days not getting any working solution.. can u please check it out this