# GetFile Cordova 3.4.0 err.code 1000

Tags: android, cordova, html5-filesystem

I try to GetFile with cordova 3.4.0 :

```
    FileManager.prototype.ReadAsTextFromFile = function (fileName, readDataCallBack) {
    var that = this;
    try {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {create: false}, 
                function (fileEntry) {
                    fileEntry.file(
                        function (file){
                            var reader = new FileReader();                             
                            reader.onloadend = readDataCallBack;
                            reader.readAsText(file);
                        }                   
                    , function(err){alert('ReadFile' + " fail: " + err.code);});
                }
            , function(err){alert('GetFile' + " fail: " + err.code);});
        }, function(err){alert('FileSystem' + " fail: " + err.code);});
    } catch (e) {
        logError(e);
    }
}
```

but obtain the err.code 1000 on the call getfile.

the file name is :

```
var fileName = "/scard/" + reliefsSubfolderName + reliefname 
               + String.fromCharCode(47) + reliefsManifestFileName;
```

/scard/my_dir_on_card/my_file_name.drd (drd is my extension but is a text file)

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what error code 1000 means?

Comment: I would like to know too.

Comment: I've found a solution. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25090074/3200341

Answer (score 7):

I guess you need to omit the leading "/" from your fileName.
Most possible cause of Error code **1000** is non-existent path file while geting a reference through getFile with create option as false

```
fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {create: false},...
```

You may try to inspect the full file path before invoking getFile and see if it is valid. Your path should not contain multiple consecutive "/" other than initial protocol. e.g **cdvfile://localhost/persistent/scard.....**

```
console.log(fileSystem.root.toURL() + fileName);
```

Comment: I was getting 1000 errors and removing a leading `/` fixed my issue.